# If clicked then load();?

Tags: jquery, menu

I have this 'sort of' pseudo code:

```
if($('#menuOption1').click()){
  $('#mainContent').load('optionContent1.html #optionContent1');
}
else if($('#menuOption2').click()){
  $('#mainContent').load('optionContent2.html #optionContent2');
}
else if($('#menuOption3').click()){
  $('#mainContent').load('optionContent3.html #optionContent3');
}
```

It's self explanatory. I have a menu with 3 options (#menuOption*) and, when I click one of them, it's suppose to load(); it's correspondent html file (optionContent*.html -  #optionContent*) into my index.html (#mainContent).
Code correction, please?

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click returns a jquery object and not a boolean what you really are after is:

```
$('#menuOption1').click(function(e) {
    $('#mainContent').load('optionContent1.html #optionContent1');
    return false;
});

$('#menuOption2').click(function(e) {
    $('#mainContent').load('optionContent2.html #optionContent2');
    return false;
});

$('#menuOption3').click(function(e) {
    $('#mainContent').load('optionContent3.html #optionContent3');
    return false;
});
```

depending on your HTML markup Im sure you could optimize the Javascript code also

Answer (score 3):

You should add your code to a click event handler like so:

```
$('#menuOption1').click(function(){
  $('#mainContent').load('optionContent1.html #optionContent1');
});
```

etc...